# Cкриншот всей страницы

Tags: python-3.x, fullpage, скриншот

Ниже приведен код, он переходит по ссылке и делает скрин видимой части экрана. В принте выводит размер моего. Как сделать так, чтобы он делал скрин всей страницы или, хотя бы, не привязывался к экрану и можно указать свои:

```
import webbrowser

import pyautogui

url = 'website'    

webbrowser.open(url, new=2, autoraise=True)

screen = pyautogui.screenshot('scrin.png')
print(screen)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример с прокруткой страницы.

```py
def scroll(image, leng, gray=False, recursion=10):
    for n in range(recursion): # Будет повторятся указное количество раз пока не найдет совпадение
        coords = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image, grayscale=gray)
        if coords is not None:
            temp_x, temp_y = pyautogui.position() # Для удобства. Сохраняем для возврата координат мышки назад после скрола
            x, y, w, _ = coords[0], coords[1], coords[2], coords[3] # Распаковка кортежа 
            pyautogui.click(x - w, y) # Корректировка для клика по окну возле указателя
            pyautogui.scroll(leng)
            pyautogui.moveTo(temp_x, temp_y) # Возвращаем курсор назад
            break # Прерываем работу цикла

        # После первой неудачи этот параметр заменяется для облегчения поиcка картинки на экране
        if gray == False: 
            gray = True 
        print('failed...', n) # n - для наглядности, можно в цикле 'for' заменить n на _ , а принт вовсе убрать

scroll('browser_scroll_button.png', -500)
```

Вот что у меня в картинке "browser_scroll_button.png": размер 9х9 px.   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но есть один нюанс, если скрол находится в верхней позиции, указатель стрелки меняет цвет. Проще говоря, нужно сделать две картинки, активно и не активного скрола и проверять их.

Также чем меньше размер вашего искомого изображения тем точнее находит этот фрагмент на екране.

Answer (score 1):

Вот как ты просил

```
import pyautogui

screen = pyautogui.screenshot('E:\\Python\\exampeles\\img1.png', region= (0,0, 300, 400))
print(screen)
```

Вот скрин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нет, я так пробовал и  сейчас.  Все равно привязывается к экрану

Comment: Вот что у меня выходит. Вроде то что нужно, вышел снимок 300х400рх

Comment: @ self_taugh да. Заработало. Просто заново ввел и все заработало. Спасибо. А вот pyautogui.scroll(10) так и не работает. Может подскажете?